# css footer issue at chrome browser

Tags: css

I have this : http://tarmeez.com.sa/labs/contactskeeperapp/

As beta test area all works fine in IE, FF, but in Сhrome i have a problem with App Image , Price and Contact us. It should be placed in footer like in IE and FF.
Any hint to fix this css ?!

Comment: Try using http://www.cssstickyfooter.com. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/wUcmP/